# Code crashing while copying an integer array to another (using integer pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am finding a hard time finding out whats wrong with my code below. I am trying to copy a simple integer pointer coming as a parameter of my structure's constructor to one of my local integer pointers (or Interger array). For some strange reason it crashes in the first iteration inside the for loop.
 Please help

```
struct mystruct{
  UINT8 command;
  UINT8 nextOffset;
  UINT8* writeBuffer1;
  UINT8 checkSum;

  mystruct( UINT8 devAddress, UINT8 commandIn, UINT8 nextOffsetIn, UINT8 bufferSizeIn, UINT8 dataBufcheckSumIn, UINT8* writeBufferIn )
  : command( commandIn )
  , nextOffset( nextOffsetIn )
  {
     writeBuffer1 = new UINT8[bufferSizeIn];
     memset( &writeBuffer1, 0, bufferSizeIn ); 
     for( int i = 0; i < bufferSizeIn; i++ ) {
         writeBuffer1[i] = writeBufferIn[i];  //Program crashes here in the first iteration itself
     } 
     checkSum = (UINT8)  ~( devAddress + command + nextOffset + dataBufcheckSumIn) + 1; dbg::info() << "Line5" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`. Then it's easy: `: writeBuffer1(writeBufferIn)`. Amazingly, then you no longer have to worry about freeing that memory and the Rule of Three/Five and such.

Comment: Should `memset( &writeBuffer1...` not be `memset( writeBuffer1...`?

Comment: or `writeBuffer1 = new UINT8[bufferSizeIn]();` to zero the buffer without `memset`.

Comment: @chris, `writeBuffer1` is already a pointer. I think the intent would be to clear the memory allocated. `memset(&writeBuffer1` would clear the pointer, hence the crash.

Comment: @Niall, I was being dumb and thinking of arrays. That's where I usually see that happen.

Comment: Thanks @chris for your quick resolution of the issue. :)

Comment: Thanks @Niall for your quick resolution of the issue. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
memset( &writeBuffer1, 0, bufferSizeIn );
```

you are not filling the buffer, but you are overwriting the member variable. Use

```
memset( writeBuffer1, 0, bufferSizeIn );
```

Comment: Thanks. I failed to notice this. :)